# MVVMCross SQLite plugin Integration Testing

Tags: sqlite, mvvmcross

I have successfully created a unit test project for my MVVMcross based application following instructions provided in step 29 of MVVMCross N+1 tutorials mocking the service actually used to load data from the database.

Now I need to implement some Integration tests of my view models using a copy of the actual database.

what I have put in place in my test class is the following:

```
[TestFixture]
public class BaseDataServiceTests
: MvxIoCSupportingTest {

  [TestFixtureSetUp]
  public void ConfigureServices() {
    base.ClearAll();
    var sqLiteConnectionFactory = new MvxWpfSqLiteConnectionFactory();

    Ioc.RegisterSingleton<ISQLiteConnectionFactory>( sqLiteConnectionFactory );
  }

  [Test]
  public void OpenDataBase() {
    //=== Arrange
    var baseDataService = new BaseDataService( Ioc.Resolve<ISQLiteConnectionFactory>() );

    //=== Act
    var sqLiteConnection = baseDataService.SqLiteConnection;

    //=== Assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOf<ISQLiteConnection>(sqLiteConnection);
  }

  [Test]
  [SetUICulture( "en-US" )]
    public void GetEnglishExcelentTranslation() {
    //=== Arrange
    const int excelentID = 10;
    var baseDataService = new BaseDataService( Ioc.Resolve<ISQLiteConnectionFactory>() );

    //=== Act
    var excelentString = baseDataService.GetLocalizedString( excelentID );

    //=== Assert
    Assert.AreEqual( "Excelent", excelentString );
  }
}
```

If I just run these test they fail on the baseDataService constructor where I use the Create method of the SqLiteConnectionFactory to openn the database file with an exception stating that it is not possible to load sqlite3 dll.

If I manually place the sqlite3.dll in the bin directory of the test project (as another post on this site suggested) the test fails on the GetLocalizedString method stating that the referenced table is not found in the database even if the table is created and filled with data.

I have the feeling I'm missing something in the SqLitePlugin startup but can't figure out how to proprly initialize it in a test project.

Test project is a standard  Windows library referencing MVVMCross libraries through NuGet and MVVMCross SQLite Community plugin.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Antonello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pathing problems with sqlite3.dll simply indicate that you need to reference that binary from your c# project. One way to do that would be to include the dll with build action "none" - but to specify "always copy to output" on the dll. Beware, though, that you may need separate 32 and 64-bit dlls depending on target machine.

For more on these types of issues, then it might be worth asking  more general "managed to native" questions -  there are plenty of people who can assist with those, but they might be "put off"/confused by too much talk of mvvm and sqlite :)

---

Once that pathing problem is solved, I don't see any reason why the sqlite plugin shouldn't work. I'd suggest you try a roundtrip unit test:

- create a db
- create a table
- add a row
- fetch the row

Something like (excuse the mobile phone typing - coding from memory without intellisense):

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTest()
{
     // your setup stuff
     var c = factory.Create("Test.db");
     c.CreateTable<Foo>();
     c.Insert(new Foo(){ Bar = 1234 });
     var result = c.Table<Foo>().ToList();
     Assert.AreEqual(1234, result[0].Bar);
 }
```

If that works, then sqlite is working (at least to a smoke test version).

Comment: Thanks for help, everything is ok now. Further reading this morning allowed me to better understand dependencies of the SQLite plugin. The table access error was caused by a mistake I keep doing while using SQLite: put the initialized db file in one directory and open it through code in another. SQLite does not complain about missing DB... it just creates an empty one....